# Is there a way to stop a tkinter class object from opening until the button is opened

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6

I have a little problem with my code. I am writing multiples classes with different GUI interfaces as a project. However, every time I import those classes the GUI window automatically opens the window and I want the window to open only when a button is clicked.

```
from FinalProject import addFlight
from FinalProject import reserveFlight



class ex:
    def __init__(self,win):
        self.win = win
        ...
        ...



def mainButtons(self):
    look = Button(self.win, text="Add New Flight",command=lambda: self.reserveMenu(1))
    look.place(relx="0.2", rely="0.3")

    res = Button(self.win, text="Book A Flight",command=lambda: self.reserveMenu(2))
    res.place(relx="0.4", rely="0.3")
      ...
      ...


def reserveMenu(self, options):
    if options == 1:
        self.flight = Toplevel(self.win)
        self.flMenu = addFlight.AddFlights(self.flight)
        self.flMenu.addingFlight()
        # call(["python","addFlight.py"])
    if options == 2:
        pass
        # self.flight = Toplevel(self.win)
        # self.flMenu = reserveFlight.ReserveFlights(self.flight)
        # self.flMenu.reserve()
        # call(["python","reserveFlight.py"]) 
       ...
       ...
```

The "reserveMenu" function works fine but is there way to suppress those import statements or at least prevent the windows from opening until the button is clicked.

I know there are other methods of opening my python code but this **HAS** to be done using **CLASSES**. Trust me I have found way easier methods of doing this. FYI, there is more code but I only copied the more important parts.

Comment: You could instead use a reserve _class_ than a method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a method you could define your reserve option windows as classes, `ReserveAdd`, `ReserveBook`, that inherit from `tkinter.Toplevel`. And all a button would do is to call them. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class ReserveAdd(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        tk.Label(self, text="This is ReserveAdd window.").pack()

class ReserveBook(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        tk.Label(self, text="This is ReserveBook window.").pack()


def res_one():
    ReserveAdd(root)

def res_two():
    ReserveBook(root)

tk.Button(root, text="Reserve Option 1", command=res_one).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Reserve Option 2", command=res_two).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the above example `Reserve Option 1` calls an instance of `ReserveAdd` class whereas `Reserve Option 2` calls an instance of a `ReserveBook` class.

I'd define a single method for buttons but that's not exactly the scope here.